# How can I combine Fine-Uploader UI template with separate JavaScript file?

Tags: aurelia, fine-uploader

I've been working on incorporating Fine-Uploader into an Aurelia project, and have made good progress thanks to recent assistance here. The problem is that the Fine-Uploader UI code, which looks great and works very well, requires that the template script and the JavaScript script both be included in the same file. This creates a problem, since I want to:

1. Create a valid Aurelia module (a custom element) that requires an `.html` and a `.js` file.
2. Use the custom element to provide modularity, so the element can be reused in several scenarios.
3. Add some business logic in the `.js` code.

So I want to have my cake and eat it too. The javascript code below works just fine, but only provides a boring button for the uploads, which is not nearly as user-friendly as the UI code.

Here's the very simple `fine-uploader.html` file:

```
<template>
    <div id="uploader" ></div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Upload image</a>
<template>
```

Here is my current `fine-uploader.js` file:

```
import 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-gallery.css';

import qq from 'fine-uploader/lib/core';
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import configOptions from './config-global';

@inject(Element)
export class FineUploader {

  @bindable endpoint;            // URL to upload to
  @bindable params = {};         // Any additional upload params
  @bindable uploaded = () => {}; // Uploaded callback for consumers

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    this.uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
      debug: true,
      button: this.element.children[0],
      callbacks: {
        onComplete: (id, name, response) => {
          if (this.uploaded) {
            this.uploaded(response);
          }
        }
      },
      request: {
        endpoint: configOptions.baseUrl + this.endpoint,
        customHeaders: {
          'authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("aurelia_id_token")}`
        },
        method: 'POST',
        params: this.params

      }

    });
  }

  detached() {
    // Apparently, no destroy() method
    // https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1038
    //this.uploader.reset();
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use the existing template script in this manner? I have had no luck in refactoring this code to load properly. It seems like a terrible waste to rebuild the very same thing that is already complete.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further digging, I was able to find a code snippet that revealed the secret. There is an attribute called `template` that needs to be referenced in the initialization object, and given a value of the template id. For example, the template id for FineUploader's Gallery UI is `qq-template-gallery`. This is referenced [here](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html) in the docs, but it was not clear until I saw a code sample.

Here is my working `.js` file:

```
import '../node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-gallery.css';
import qq from 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader';
import {bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import configOptions from './config-global';

@inject(Element)
export class FineUploader {

  @bindable endpoint;            // URL to upload to
  @bindable params = {};         // Any additional upload params
  @bindable uploaded = () => {}; // Uploaded callback for consumers
  @bindable itemlimit = 50;           // integer
  @bindable allowedextensions = [];   // array of strings - do not use . in ext name

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    this.uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
      debug: true,
      element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
      template: 'qq-template-gallery',
      callbacks: {
        onComplete: (id, name, response) => {
          if (this.uploaded) {
            this.uploaded(response);
          }
        }
      },
      validation: {
        itemLimit: this.itemlimit,
        allowedExtensions: this.allowedextensions
      },
      request: {
        endpoint: configOptions.baseUrl + this.endpoint,
        customHeaders: {
          'authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("aurelia_id_token")}`
        },
        method: 'POST',
        params: this.params 
      }
    });
  }

  detached() {
    // Apparently, no destroy() method
    // https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1038
    //this.uploader.reset();
  }
}
```